# Go: How to receive a whole UDP Datagram

Tags: go, udp

My Problem: With net.Read... Methods copy only the number of bytes of the size of the given byte-array or slice. I don't want to allocate the maximum UDP datagram of 64 kB every time of course.

Is there a `go` way to determine the size of the datagram (which is in the datagram header) or read again until the datagram is completely read?

Comment: Checked the implementation: Go implements directly what socket.h offers. So no other choice.

Comment: [Here is another question asking the same thing about the C interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446887/udp-read-data-from-the-queue-in-chunks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ReadFromUDP](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.ReadFromUDP):

```
func (c *UDPConn) ReadFromUDP(b []byte) (n int, addr *UDPAddr, err error)
```

> > ReadFromUDP reads a UDP packet from c, copying the payload into b. It returns the number of bytes copied into b and the return address that was on the packet.

The packet size should be available from `n`, which you can then use to define a custom slice (or other data structure) to store the datagrams in. This relies on the datagram size not changing during the session, which it really shouldn't.

Comment: Problem is: The datagram size changes, i implement OSC ( www.opensoundcontrol.org) - it's not my decision. I have never seen a OSC datagram larger then 1024 bytes in the wild, but theoretically...

Comment: No it doesn't work like @0x434D53 wants. I was looking for the same thing. What I need is the 5th and 6th bytes from the headers. It is a 16bits number where the max is 65536 - 8. I've spend some time looking at the code but it goes too deep into linux internals.
Allocating only 8 bytes for the headers is enough to know the size of the buffer the packet really needs.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in a UDP protocol packet sizes are known in advance, and it's usually much smaller, in the order of 1.5k or less.

What you can do is preallocate a maximum size static buffer for all reads, then once you know the size of the datagram you've read from the socket, allocate a byte array with the actual size and copy the data to it. I don't think you can do extra reads of the same datagram.

Comment: Thanks, did fear that. I exactly wanted to avoid that one additional copy step.